# Custom activation in tensorflow.js (Swish)

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm trying to implement a custom activation (Swish) function in tensorflow.js.
How can I do this?

I didn't find any info for a custom activation function, but for adding a [custom layer](https://gist.github.com/caisq/33ed021e0c7b9d0e728cb1dce399527d). So I implemented a custom layer that I added manually after layers that I didn't assign any activations to. It seems to work, but it is quite cumbersome in the code (especially the model definition). How can I extend the activation class directly to get an activation function that I can call inside any layer definition? The activation functions are defined here https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-layers/blob/master/src/activations.ts in the TF.js code.
It should work like this:
`const dense_layer = tf.layers.dense({units: 8, activation: my_Swish});`

I put together my code where I extend a layer to act like an activation function. This is the class Swish. I also tried extending tf.layers.activations via the Swich2 class but calling it yields an error.

```
errors.ts:48 Uncaught Error: activation: Improper config format: {"_callHook":null,"_addedWeightNames":[],"_stateful":false,"id":1,"activityRegularizer":null,"inputSpec":null,"supportsMasking":true,"_trainableWeights":[],"_nonTrainableWeights":[],"_losses":[],"_updates":[],"_built":false,"inboundNodes":[],"outboundNodes":[],"name":"activation_Activation1","trainable_":true,"initialWeights":null,"_refCount":null,"fastWeightInitDuringBuild":false,"activation":{}}.
'className' and 'config' must set.
    at new e (errors.ts:48)
    at Lp (generic_utils.ts:227)
    at rm (activations.ts:218)
    at im (activations.ts:239)
    at new e (core.ts:218)
    at Object.dense (exports_layers.ts:524)
    at tf.html:77
```

I've added both test cases in the code. Just uncomment line 64 and 66 to see the respective errors. My tf_test.html (can be run locally in Browser):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js, Plotly for plots -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>
      <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->    
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="myDiv"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  <script>
    // Notice there is no 'import' statement. 'tf' is available on the index-page
    // because of the script tag above.

    // custom layer
    // https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/custom-layer/custom_layer.js
    // https://gist.github.com/caisq/33ed021e0c7b9d0e728cb1dce399527d
    // https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-layers/blob/master/src/activations.ts
    class Swish extends tf.layers.Layer {
      //static className = 'Swish';
      constructor(config) {
        super(config);
        this.alpha = config.alpha;
      }

      call(input) {
        return tf.tidy(() => {
          const x = input[0]; //tf.getExactlyOneTensor(input);
          return tf.sigmoid(x.mul(this.alpha)).mul(x);
        });
      }

      computeOutputShape(inputShape){
        return inputShape;
      }

      static get className() {
      return 'Swish';
      }

      getConfig() {
        const config = {alpha: this.alpha};
        const baseConfig = super.getConfig();
        Object.assign(config, baseConfig);
        return config;
      }
    }

    tf.serialization.registerClass(Swish);

    class Swish2 extends tf.layers.activation {
      static get className() {return 'Swish2'};
      apply(x, alpha = 1) {
        return tf.sigmoid(x.mul(this.alpha)).mul(x);
      }
    }
    tf.serialization.registerClass(Swish2);

    const sw = new Swish({alpha: 1});
    const sw2 = new Swish2(1);
    // create Model
    const m_in = tf.input({shape: [1]});
    // this doesn't work!!! activations have to be defined manually as layers and then added, see below
    //const test = tf.layers.dense({units: 8, activation: sw}).apply(m_in);
    // sw2 can't be called this way either, yields 'Improper config format' error
    //const test2 = tf.layers.dense({units: 8, activation: sw2}).apply(m_in);
    const dense1 = tf.layers.dense({units: 8}).apply(m_in);
    const swa = sw.apply(dense1);
    const m_out = tf.layers.dense({units: 1}).apply(swa);
    const model = tf.model({inputs: m_in, outputs: m_out});

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is wrong with your code, but [it looks like](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1804) you did figure out how to add custom activation functions, you just never posted an answer here;)

Thanks to your and other people's efforts, the swish activation function [was added to tfjs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/pull/3879) in late 2020.

It turned out to be pretty simple, based on the linked PR an experienced programmer should have no problem forking the repo and adding new activation functions to tfjs/tfjs-layers/src/activations.ts.

But it's even simpler to not fork the repo, and instead of modifying the tfjs source, just adding your custom activation function in a separate file.

For the sake of this example I'm going to implement a "hard" hyperbolic tangent function, which gives a segment-wise linear approximation of `tanh` the same way `hardSigmoid` gives an appoximation of the normal `sigmoid`.

Let's do this in 7 easy steps:

1 - Create a new file called hardTanh.ts

2 - Start with these imports, we are going to need them

```
import * as tfc from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
import {serialization, Tensor, tidy} from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
```

3 - Copy and paste the `Activation` class from activations.ts, as it does not seem to be exposed on the API, but we need it, too

```
export abstract class Activation extends serialization.Serializable {
  abstract apply(tensor: Tensor, axis?: number): Tensor;
  getConfig(): serialization.ConfigDict {
    return {};
  }
}
```

4 - Implement `hardTanh` as a `Tensor` to `Tensor` function, wrap the return value in a `tidy` call

```
export function hardTanh(x: Tensor): Tensor {
  return tidy(() => {
    const y = tfc.mul(.5, x);
    return tfc.clipByValue(y, -1, 1);
  });
}
```

5 - Create a wrapper class that extends `Activation`

```
export class HardTanh extends Activation {
  /** @nocollapse */
  static readonly className = 'hardTanh';
  apply(x: Tensor): Tensor {
    return hardTanh(x);
  }
}
```

6 - Register the class for serialization

```
serialization.registerClass(HardTanh);
```

7 - Compile `hardTanh.ts` to `hardTanh.js`, then you can import your new activation function as `import {HardTanh} from './hardTanh';`, and reference it through the name `'hardTanh'` (defined in step 5), for example you can write something like

```
model.add(tf.layers.lstm({
  units: lstmLayerSizeDefinedSomewhereElse,
  activation: 'hardTanh'
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation, the activation property of the tf.layers.dense is a string: `'elu'|'hardSigmoid'|'linear'|'relu'|'relu6'| 'selu'|'sigmoid'|'softmax'|'softplus'|'softsign'|'tanh'`. By using an instance of tf.layers.activation.layer, the following error is thrown:

> ctivation: Improper config format: {"_callHook":null,"_addedWeightNames":[],"_stateful":false,"id":0,"activityRegularizer":null,"inputSpec":null,"supportsMasking":true,"_trainableWeights":[],"_nonTrainableWeights":[],"_losses":[],"_updates":[],"_built":false,"inboundNodes":[],"outboundNodes":[],"name":"activation_Activation1","trainable_":true,"initialWeights":null,"_refCount":null,"fastWeightInitDuringBuild":false,"activation":{},"alpha":1}.

The error indicates that className is not set nor is the config since the `getActivation` of the Activation class is returning an empty object. Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-layers/blob/v1.2.6/src/activations.ts#L223), we can see that if the activation is not a string, an empty Layer is returned with no classname, nor config.

The proper way of setting a custom activation layer, is by applying it as a layer as indicated in the [doc](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#layers.activation).

Comment: The linked documentation doesn't deal with any custom activation function. It shows an activation function that is already included in the tensorflow.js library (`'relu6'`). The question is about how to use a custom activation function, one that is NOT already included in the tensorflow.js library. (Swish was not included in tensorflow.js at the time this question was asked, but the question could still be useful for other activation functions that are not included in tensorflow.js.)

Comment: I think that you misread my answer. `Swish` was not and is still not part of tensorflow.js. My answer is saying that the activation property of a layer expects a string and not a class instance. But if a custom activation is to be applied, it has to be done by applying the custom activation as a model layer

Comment: Nothing in your answer shows how to "apply the custom activation as a model layer". You're not answering the question that is asked.

Comment: "the documentation that is linked clearly shows how to do it" - This is false. The documentation that is linked does not show how to do it.